# Express.js calls built-in error handler middleware instead of custom error handler

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, routes, middleware

I have a problem where I have an express application with a router. The router uses two sub-routers. First sub-router mounts a middleware that calls the error-handling middleware. The second sub-router mounts an error handling middleware. However, instead of my custom error handler, it uses the built-in error handler.

I created a simple project to reproduce the problem.

Source folder:

*/app.js

/router.js

/sub_router_a.js

/sub_routre_b.js*

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = require('./router')

const app = express()

app.use(router)

app.listen(3003, () => {
    console.log(`app listening on port 3003`)
})
```

router.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const sub_router_a = require('./sub_router_a')
const sub_router_b = require('./sub_router_b')

router.use(sub_router_a)
router.use(sub_router_b)

module.exports = router
```

sub_router_a.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.use(
    function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('a')
        return next('NOT WANTED ERROR MESSAGE')
    }
)

module.exports = router
```

sub_router_b.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.use(
    function (err, req, res, next) {
        console.log('b')
        return res.send('WANTED ERROR MESSAGE')
    }
)

module.exports = router
```

If I make a request, I get the 'NOT WANTED ERROR MESSAGE' in my browser.

My question: **why is that?** Please don't tell me to mount the error handler in app.js, yes, that works, but I wonder if it's possible to mount an error handler in a sub-router.

Comment: _"but I wonder if it's possible to mount an error handler in a sub-router"_. Not a _global_ error handler, no. Any error handlers you mount in a sub-router only handle errors that occur within that sub-router.

Comment: Can you refer to the documentation? I've read the whole "Error handling" part of express docs, and this is not mentioned.

Comment: It's implied in the documentation for [`express.Router`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router): _"A `Router` instance is a complete middleware and routing system; for this reason, it is often referred to as a “mini-app”."_

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's unclear what responsibilities does this statement cover, and what it doesn't :)

Comment: If you consider an error handler to be just a special for of middleware (which it is), it might make more sense. Regular middleware mounted on a `Router` is only valid "inside" that router, so it seems reasonable that the same rules apply to an error handler middleware.